# 500 error when using nbviewer in IPython

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to publish my IPython notebook using nbviewer. However, even after I added the script:

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    IPython.load_extensions("gist");
});
```

to my custom.js found in: `$(ipython locate profile)/static/custom/custom.js`, I get a 500 error ( http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/roxyboy/992fc15dc0e6209825de ). Could someone tell me how to resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well something went wrong, and you did nothing bad. You should fill a bug report.